# $ionicPlatform.ready() not firing, Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get push notifications working on an Ionic Android app based entirely of a single WebView, served via `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`.

The `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function never calls and thus, the `Ionic.Push` object is never created (no device token logged). I'm able to run `console.log` before `$ionicPlatform.ready()` is called, inside of the run function, but not inside of the callback from `$ionicPlatform.ready()`.

Am I missing something obvious?

**app.js**

```
var websiteURL = 'http://example.com';

angular.module('abc', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      //stops the viewport from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    // bootstrap for push notifications, set debug to true to use Ionic's push notification platform, not Google's/Apple's
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    // register the apps token so that the ionic platform can communicate with it
    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
  });
})

.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.openWebsite = function()
  {
   // open up the peoplemovers site in the in app browser window
   window.open(websiteURL,'_self'); 
  };
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="abc">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-content ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="openWebsite()" padding="true">
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I've reinstalled Ionic, Cordova, node, npm, Android Studio and the Android SDKs.

The URL that window.open calls has a file selection button that used to crash the app when a file was selected from the Android "Gallery" tab, which was due to some Android permissions issues. A forum post suggested adding the `cordova-plugin-camera` plugin to add the permissions necessary and this DID solve the issue.

However, now the `$ionicPlatform.ready` call isn't being made. Even if I run `ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera` I can't seem to get `$ionicPlatform.ready` to call anymore.

I do not receive any error messages, the app loads fine. This behavior is consistent across testing on an LG Android 6.0 phone, the Android Emulator (SDK 23) and Genymotion emulator.

Is there an easier way to get file permissions from the phone besides the camera plugin? If not, is there a setting or config line that I need to get the `$ionicPlatform.ready` function to fire?

Here's the new app.js:

```
var websiteURL = 'http://example.com';

angular.module('lmgapp', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    console.log('firing');

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.openWebsite = function()
  {
    console.log('in the controller');
   // open up the site in the in app browser window
   window.open(websiteURL,'_self'); 
  };
});
```

And here's the new index.html after reinstallation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="lmgapp">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-content ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="openWebsite()">
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$ionicPlatform.ready is not firing because you don't have cordova. It is commented out.

Comment: + ionic-platform-web-client is deprecated. It is replaced by Ionic Cloud Client. Please see for migration : http://docs.ionic.io/migration.html

Comment: ionicPlatform.ready should be called whether you have cordova or not. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @Ladmerc I'm not receiving any error messages - the app will still run.

Comment: @e666 I must have been on an older version of Ionic. cordova.js was commented out from the creation of the app. Once I reinstalled all the necessary software with the new versions, cordova.js was added by default. I updated my question with these changes.

Comment: @Alex, I updated to the new version of Cordova and cordova.js was now added as a default. Unfortunately, I'm still getting some similar behavior. I found out some new information about the situation and added it as an edit to my question. Thanks.